# How to add another overlay item to a android mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I need to add another overlay item to a mapview. I have used the standard android developers guide to google maps. I currently have the mapview within a tab. I would really appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Below are my java classes:

```
public class Mapview extends MapActivity {

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // JD sports marker begin
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.jd_sports_logo);
        //Passes drawable(jd sports logo) into HelloItemizedOverlay class
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = 
                new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

        double latitude = 51.545538;
        double longitude = -0.477247;
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1e6), 
                (int)(longitude * 1e6));

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "JD Sports", 
                "This is a sports shop");

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        // JD sports marker ends

        // Fitness first marker begin
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays1 = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable1 = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.fitness_first_logo);
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay1 = 
                new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

        double latitude1 = 51.545157;
        double longitude1 = -0.477247;
        GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1e6), 
                (int)(longitude * 1e6));

        OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point, "JD Sports",
                "This is a sports shop");

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        // Fitness first marker ends
    }

}
```

My HelloItemizedOverlay class:

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays1 = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {

        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(defaultMarker);
        Context mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        Context mContext = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem on adding another layer just as you did with the first one itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem), and it would be nicer if you could format all that is code as code...

Answer (score 1):

```
OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point, "JD Sports, ...
```

Should read

```
OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, "JD Sports", ...
```

Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
Drawable drawable1 = this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.fitness_first_logo);
boundCenterBottom(drawable1);
...
```